# How to create backspace button in calculator?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

```
import tkinter as tk



from tkinter import *



root=tk.Tk()


root.geometry("720x1320")


root.title('Calculator')


root.resizable(0, 0)



root['background']='#444444'


def bclick(num):
    global exp
    exp= exp+str(num)
    input.set(exp)



def bclear():
    global exp
    exp=""
    input.set("")



def bequal():
    global exp
    result=str(eval(exp))
    input.set(result)
    exp=""


exp=""


input=StringVar()


input_frame = Frame(root, width = 312, height = 100, bd = 0, highlightbackground = "black", highlightcolor = "black", highlightthickness = 1)
input_frame.pack(side = TOP)



#label
dis=Entry(input_frame,textvariable=input,bg='#cccccc',fg='#000000',justify=RIGHT,font= ("sans-serif 16"))


dis.place(x=0,y=0)
dis.pack(ipady=197)

#0 row
bC=tk.Button(root,text='C',padx=166,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclear())
bC.place(x=0,y=479)


bX=tk.Button(root,text='X',padx=78,pady=40,fg='#FFFFFF',bg='#d21405',font=('sans-serif, 14'))

bX.place(x=360,y=479)

bdiv=tk.Button(root,text='÷',padx=78,pady=40,fg='#ffffff',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("/"),bg='#1138be')
bdiv.place(x=540,y=479)

#1 row done
b7=tk.Button(root,text='7',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("7"))
b7.place(x=0,y=631)

b8=tk.Button(root,text='8',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("8"))
b8.place(x=180,y=631)
b9=tk.Button(root,text='9',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("9"))
b9.place(x=360,y=631)

bmul=tk.Button(root,text='×',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#1138be',fg='#ffffff',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("*"))
bmul.place(x=540,y=631)
#2 row


b4=tk.Button(root,text='4',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("4"))
b4.place(x=0,y=783)

b5=tk.Button(root,text='5',padx=80,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("5"))
b5.place(x=180,y=783)

b6=tk.Button(root,text='6',padx=79,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("6"))
b6.place(x=360,y=783)

badd=tk.Button(root,text='+',padx=80,pady=40,bg='#1138be',fg='#ffffff',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("+"))
badd.place(x=540,y=783)
#3row


b1=tk.Button(root,text='1',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("1"))
b1.place(x=0,y=935)

b2=tk.Button(root,text='2',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("2"))
b2.place(x=180,y=935)

b3=tk.Button(root,text='3',padx=78,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("3"))
b3.place(x=360,y=935)

bsub=tk.Button(root,text='-',padx=82,pady=40,bg='#1138be',fg='#ffffff',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("-"))
bsub.place(x=540,y=935)
#4 row


b0=tk.Button(root,text='0',padx=165,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("0"))
b0.place(x=0,y=1087)

bdot=tk.Button(root,text='.',padx=85,pady=40,bg='#FFFFFF',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bclick("."))
bdot.place(x=360,y=1087)

bans=tk.Button(root,text='=',padx=80,pady=40,bg='#002366',fg='#ffffff',font=('sans-serif, 14'),command=lambda:bequal())
bans.place(x=540,y=1087)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This isn't a question. Please provide some supporting information and format your code properly so it can be read and understood. Also, after reading through your code I feel I should point out that `input` is a named function in Python. You're masking that function by using it as a variable name: `input=StringVar()`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is the same way you've done the last buttons instead of using the text='1' or a number just change it to text='backspace'.

As for the logic behind it since you have a global exp variable storing the maths equation created using the calculator you will need to remove the last bit of the equation added. i.e. if the equation was `12 + 15 + 17 - 20` you'd need to look through it and remove `20` because that was the last part of the equation. If they hit backspace again you'd need to remove the `-`.

So you're looking to create a function called `bRemove()` which removes the last part of your equation.

hint : to look at the last character in your string you can access it doing exp[len(exp)-1], you can check if this is a number and if it is you can remove it and look at the next element in the string (exp[len(exp)-2]) and then see if that is also a number.

[

also some general stack overflow advice to help you on your programming journey, it's better to be more specific about the help requested - some background information is nice and if you are going tto paste code you should use the ``` notation which lets you turn code into blocked code like this

```
block of code
```

]

Answer (score 0):

Try this in my example.

```
from tkinter import *


#definging height and width of button.
button_height=1
button_width=3
#defining height and width of screen
screen_width =450
screen_height= 600

root=Tk()
root.title("SIMPLE CALCULATOR")
root.geometry(f"{screen_width}x{screen_height}")
root.maxsize(screen_width,screen_height)
root.minsize(screen_width,screen_height)
root.configure(background="gray")

scvalue=StringVar()
scvalue.set("")

#This defines the function for click event
def click_me(event):
    value=event= event.widget.cget("text")
    #print(value)
    if value == "=":
        try:
            if scvalue.get().isdigit():
                finalvalue= int(scvalue.get())
            else:
                finalvalue=eval(scvalue.get())
                scvalue.set(finalvalue)
                screen.update()
        except:
            scvalue.set(scvalue.get()[:-1])
            screen.update()
    elif value=="<=":        #for backspace
        scvalue.set(scvalue.get()[:-1])
        screen.update()
    elif value =="1/x":      #for calculating reciprocal
        if scvalue.get().isdigit():
            val=int(scvalue.get())
            scvalue.set(1/val)
            screen.update()
        else:
            scvalue.set("Unknown error")

    elif value== "C":          #for clearing the screen.
        scvalue.set("")
        screen.update()
    else:
        scvalue.set(scvalue.get() +value)
        screen.update()

screen= Entry(root,textvar=scvalue,font="lucida 40 bold" ,justify=RIGHT)

screen.pack(fill=X,padx=5,pady=5)

#list of all the inputs
valuelist=["/","%","C","<=","7","8","9","*","4","5","6","-","1","2","3","+","1/x","0",".","="]

#this loop
for i in range(20):
    if i%4 == 0:
        frame=Frame(root,bg="gray")
        frame.pack()
    b=Button(frame,text=valuelist[i],height=button_height,width=button_width,font="lucida 35 bold")
    b.bind("<Button-1>",click_me)
    b.pack(side=LEFT,padx=3,pady=3)

root.mainloop()
```